# How can I minimize the costs associated with using Firebase Storage for displaying images inside a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I understand that Firebase Storage can be costly when it comes to storing and retrieving large amounts of data.

I am looking for an efficient and cost-effective solution to display images in my app.

Are there any best practices or techniques that I can implement to reduce the expenses associated with Firebase Storage?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to optimize the cost of Firebase Storage while still being able to display images in my RecyclerView.

Note, I am already using the Paging 3 library in my RecyclerView.

Comment: Cache images ..

Comment: @Manohar Caching images is not an effective solution as over time, the number of images in the cache will increase, eventually leading to a lack of memory storage capacity.

Comment: In the long run, consider using a backend or a website & use a CDN like BunnyCDN, Cloudfront or Cloudflare (has a free plan as well) with it.

Comment: @TahaSami If you are using library like glide you can set the max cache size .